# WebStorm - How can I fix all syntax errors?

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I mistakenly forgot to place 4 commas in my javascript file today. WebStorm recognized the problem... there were 4 red squiggly lines indicating where I should place the missing commas. Rather than fix each syntax error manually, is there a way to fix all of them at once?

Comment: Maybe, but do you trust the heuristics to get it right?

Comment: From what I've seen so far, WebStorm has been pretty good at identifying most problems and coming up with the correct solution. Do you think otherwise?

Comment: If it fixes something the wrong way, you might never even see the problem.

Comment: True, but if the changes needed are minor(ex: 4 missing commas), it would seem like a useful option to have... you wouldn't happen to know how to do it, would you?

Comment: In some cases a regex might work. For instance you can perform something as `s/mymethod\(([^\)])\)/mymethod\(\1,null,arg1,arg2,arg3\)/g` using `awk`.

Comment: `Code | Inspect Code...` -- it will bring all issues found in the file/folder/scope/project (whatever scope you will choose) in one list where you can see and fix them (**including batch fix**).